# Terraform: Type constraints on local variables

Tags: types, terraform

I know that in Terraform we can define variables and assign them types like so

```
variable "foo" {
   type= string
   default= "foo"
}
```

it's also possible to define locals like

```
locals {
   foo = {
      a = "foo"
      b = "bar"
   }
}
```

What I want is a combination of the two - if possible. So is there a way to impose type constraints on local vars without the need to define a corresponding variables file?? So, in other words can I have something like

```
locals {
   a = map(string)
   a = {
     foo = string,
     foo = "foo"
   }
}
```

This is just a dummy definition to showcase that I am searching for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform has no syntax to directly write down a type constraint for a local value; the type is always inferred from the result of the expression.

However, if you do want this value to be specifically a map of string, rather than `object({ a = string, b = string })` as Terraform would infer by default, you can convert that value to a map using [the `tomap` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/tomap.html):

```
locals {
 foo = tomap({
   a = "foo"
   b = "bar"
 })
}
```

The `tomap` function will notice that all of the attribute types are `string` and thus produce a `map(string)` value as its result.

If there were not any single type that all of the element values could convert to (as is required for a map type in Terraform) then `tomap` would return an error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a scenario where I had to do a constraint on var, this is what I ended up with, will not work for locals:

```
variable "test_vars" {
  type = list(object({
    feature_flag  = bool
    value         = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      feature_flag  = 9
      value         = "WORLD"
  }]
}

output "test" {
  value = var.test_vars
}
```

It will throw an error:

```
This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint: element 0: attribute "feature_flag": bool required.
```